# ListView dynamic onClickListener USING Database ID

Tags: android

I'm creating a restaurant menu app with categories and items loaded from database and put them in a listview. Every category has it's own items. I would like to following behaviour: when I click on some category it should go to another activity and list it's items of the category id that listed in DB.
How do I create a dynamic onItemClickListener to send that ID to another activity to load it's items?

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve the problem?

Comment: I suggest to use Intents with the categories ID to start a new Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not about dynamic listener. Listener should be only one which would send chosen category id to somewhere where you could use further. Like sending it in intent's bundle to some activity.